# PHP Regex: Extracting content from piped curly braces

Tags: php, regex, pipe, brackets, curly-braces

I'm trying to extract and replace Wikipedia curly braces content with no success.

In the string below, I'd like to be able to replace `{{Nihongo|Pang|ãƒ‘ãƒ³|Pan}}` by `Pang`

```
$text = "Buster Bros, also called {{Nihongo|Pang|ãƒ‘ãƒ³|Pan}} and {{Nihongo|Pomping World|ãƒãƒ³ãƒ”ãƒ³ã‚°ãƒ»ãƒ¯ãƒ¼ãƒ«ãƒ‰|Ponpingu WÄrudo|lead=yes}}, is a cooperative two-player arcade video game released in 1989 by Capcom";
```

I tried many combinations of regex in my preg_replace such as the one below with no luck so far

```
$text = preg_replace('/\{\{({^:\|\}}+)\|({^:\}}+)\}\}/', "$2", $text);
```

Comment: Are you wanting to replace only the first group of brackets with `Pang` or all groups of brackets with the second word in that group? You need to state this clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not stated clearly.

If you are only wanting to replace the first occurrence of curly braces in your **specific** data with the second element in that group, you could use a *negative lookahead* to match the following comma.

```
$text = preg_replace('/{{[^|]*\|([^|]++)\|[^{}]++}}(?!,)/', '$1', $text);
```

Outputs..

```
Buster Bros, also called Pang and {{Nihongo|Pomping World|ãƒãƒ³ãƒ”ãƒ³ã‚°ãƒ»ãƒ¯ãƒ¼ãƒ«ãƒ‰|Ponpingu WÄrudo|lead=yes}}, is a cooperative two-player arcade video game released in 1989 by Capcom
```

If you want to replace every occurrence of curly braces with the second element in that group.

```
$text = preg_replace('/{{[^|]*\|([^|]++)\|[^{}]++}}/', '$1', $text);
```

Outputs..

```
Buster Bros, also called Pang and Pomping World, is a cooperative two-player arcade video game released in 1989 by Capcom
```

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for providing both. That's second one I needed. Perfect, now I'll study it more (been doing PHP since PHP/FI 2, but still in trouble with that)

Comment: Glad I could help. Let me know if you have another question.

Comment: I might, now trying to remove <ref>various content here</ref> content from the same pages :D

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well, you want to replace a list inside double curly brackets by the second item of the list. To do this, you can try:

```
$text = preg_replace('/{{[^|]*+\|([^|]++)(?>[^}]++|}(?!}))*+}}/', '$1', $text);
```

Details:

```
{{          # litteral curly brackets (no need to escape them)
[^|]*+      # first item: all that is not a `|` zero or more times
\|          # litteral `|` (must be escaped)
([^|]++)    # second item in a capture group 
(?>         # content until `}}` in a non capturing group (atomic)
    [^}]++  # all characters except `}`
  |         # OR
    }(?!})  # `}` not followed by another `}`
)*+         # repeat the group zero or more times
}}          # litteral `}}` (no need to escape them too)
```